# React-router doesn't handle hash from my path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I have my react-router setup like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
     {/* other routes */}
</Router>
```

I'm using `browserHistory` from react-router.

My application is on Amazon S3 bucket and when I make initial request everything works fine on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari, Edge and IE it doesn't work.

I see hash added in the path which is added on the server.

So basically if I enter:

> https://example/foo

It becomes:

> https://example/#/foo

My react-router doesn't know how to route it properly since no route with hash is defined in my routes. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory` which is also available in React router via `import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'`. ( `eg. <Router history={hashHistory}>` instead of `<Router history={browserHistory}>` )